# How do I turn dictionary object values into columns for .csv export?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, json, dictionary

I've trained a random forest classifier, and classifier.explain() gives a dictionary containing the following keys:

```
0: classes
1: importance
2: numberOfTrees
3: outOfBagErrorEstimate
4: trees
```

I store the importances in a feature, which are placed into a feature collection as such:

```
var NewFeatureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(myData.map(function(other variables){
        
        various code eventually leading to...

        var outFeat = ee.Feature(null, {
              'accRT': trainedClassifier.confusionMatrix().accuracy(),
              'accRV': classifiedValData.errorMatrix('class', "classification").accuracy(),
               ...
              'importances': ee.List(trainedClass.explain().get('importance'))
          });
```

When I export this feature collection as a .csv, 'accRT' and 'accRV' are fine, just a single value in each column, but the contents of the 'importances' column are formatted like this:

```
{variable1=80.10020492, variable2=76.18230, ... variableN=116.234236}
```

Print() indicates that the column is Dictionary<Float> while the rest are just Float.

How do I split the importances into multiple columns before export?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign properties to a variable (dict) and append the importance dict. The method `combine` of `ee.Classifier` returns a dictionary, not a list (as you're casting it to)

(disclaimer: I didn't try this code)

```
var NewFeatureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(myData.map(function(other variables){
        
        // various code eventually leading to...
        var properties = ee.Dictionary({
            'accRT': trainedClassifier.confusionMatrix().accuracy(),
            'accRV': classifiedValData.errorMatrix('class', "classification").accuracy()
        })
        properties = properties.combine(ee.Dictionary(trainedClass.explain().get('importance')))
        var outFeat = ee.Feature(null, properties);
}
```

Comment: I'm given the error that "properties.combine is not a function."

Edit: changed it to
```
var properties = ee.Dictionary({
       'accRT': ...});
```
and was able to combine them.

Comment: that was exactly the issue, I modified the answer to be correct